# jq, replace null values on any level, not touching non-null or not existing

Tags: json, replace, jq

please assist to a newbie in jq. :)

I have to update a field with specific name that might occur on any level of JSON structure - and might not. Like with all *.description fields in JSON below:

```
{
        "a": {
                "b": [{
                                "name": "b0",
                                "description": "b0 has description"
                        },
                        {
                                "name": "b1",
                                "description": null
                        },
                        {
                                "name": "b2"
                        }
                ],
                "description": null
        },
        "s": "Some string value"
}
```

I need to update "description" value with some dummy value if only it has null value, but do not touch existing values and do not create new fields where they do not exist. So desired result in this case is:

```
{
        "a": {
                "b": [{
                                "name": "b0",
                                "description": "b0 has description"
                        },
                        {
                                "name": "b1",
                                "description": "DUMMY DESCRIPTION"
                        },
                        {
                                "name": "b2"
                        }
                ],
                "description": "DUMMY DESCRIPTION"
        },
        "s": "Some string value"
}
```

Here, .a.b[0].description left untouched because it existed and was not null; .a.b[1].description and .a.description are forced to "DUMMY DESCRIPTION" because these field existed and were null; and .a.b[2] as well as root level left untouched because there was no description field at all.

If for example I try to use command on known paths like below

```
jq '.known.level.description //= "DUMMY DESCRIPTION"' ........
```

it fails to skip non-existing fields like .a.b[2].description; and, sure, it works on known positions in JSON only. And if I try to do recursive search like:

```
jq '.. | .description? //= "DUMMY DESCRIPTION"' ........
```

it does not seem to work correctly on arrays.

What's the correct approach to walk through entire JSON in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the correct approach to walk through entire JSON in this case?

The answer is `walk`!

If your jq does not already have `walk/1`, you can google for it easily enough (jq "def walk"), and then include its def before using it, e.g. as follows:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("description") and .description == null
     then .description = "DUMMY DESCRIPTION"
     else . end)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you could consider is using streams. You'll get paths and values to every item in the input. With that you could look for name/value pairs with the name `"description"` and update the value.

```
$ jq --arg replacement "DUMMY DESCRIPTION" '
fromstream(tostream | if length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "description"
    then .[1] |= (. // $replacement)
    else .
end)
' input.json
```

Comment: Careful: jq -n 'false // 1' # => 1